# DownloadURL return null in below code

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

When I change the file its successfully updated in firebase storage but I when I try to get downloadURL its show null.

```
fileChange(event: any) {
    const imageFolder: string = this.employee.id;
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    const file: File = fileList[0];
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`${imageFolder}/profile.jpg`).put(file);
    console.log(storageRef.snapshot.downloadURL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The put() is asynchronous. If you want to get the url after the file is uploaded you have to do it like this:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child(`${imageFolder}/profile.jpg`).put(file).then((snapshot) => {
     storageRef  = snapshot.downloadURL:
     console.log(snapshot.downloadURL);
});
```